# ASP.NET C# Bool type casting

Tags: c#, asp.net, boolean

This code throwing out an error:

```
    bool status1 = (bool)Cache["cache_req_head"];
    bool status2 = (bool)Cache["cache_super"];
    bool status3 = (bool)Cache["cache_head"];
```

This is how the cache variables were set:

```
if (checkreqhead == true)
        {
            Cache["cache_req_head"] = true;
        }
        else if (checksuper == true)
        {
            Cache["cache_super"] = true;
        }
        else if (checkhead == true)
        {
            Cache["cache_head"] = true;
        }
```

Coming from `PHP` background, this is awkward. The error is:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object

I'm certain it is something really simple, but probably I can't spot it.

THANKS ALL FOR HELPING :)

Comment: BTW: the "==true" in your if statements are redundant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Object reference not set to an instance of an object" is c# lingo for "you did something stupid with a `null` value"

If the Cache is empty you need to check that first

```
bool status1 = (bool)Cache["cache_req_head"];
```

should be

```
bool status1 = false;
if (Cache["cache_req_head"] != null)
{
   status1 = (bool)Cache["cache_req_head"];
}
```

This is an effect of the fact that value types (like bool, int, etc) in c# can not be null. There is a wrapper, `Nullable<T>` with the shorthand `T?` that you can use if you want to allow null values for the value types.

You can cast your value to a `bool?` since that allows for `null`.

```
bool? status1 = (bool?)Cache["cache_req_head"];
```

You can then check `status1 == null` or `status1.HasValue`, to get the actual bool value you need to pick it out with `status1.Value`. If you pick `status1.Value` while `status1 == null` you will get a runtime exception like the one you just got.

Comment: I haven't tried that last thing, but would it work?  I would think you'd need to say: bool? status1 = Cache["cache_req_head"] as bool?

Comment: @MikeChristensen, My test code `object oBool = null;    bool? nBool = oBool as bool?;    Console.WriteLine(nBool);    oBool = false;    nBool = oBool as bool?;    Console.WriteLine(nBool);` seems to work OK.

Comment: @MikeChristensen `as bool` won't work since `as T` requires `T` to be a reference type. (how could `as` otherwise return null when the type is incorrect?)

Comment: I didn't say as bool, I said "as bool?"

Comment: @MikeChristensen, aha. Well, `as bool?` is only required if you want to handle other types than bool in the same Cache key. BTW, have a look at [Markdown in comments](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2115/text-formatting-now-allowed-in-comments-list-of-proven-and-disproven-abilities)

Comment: its cool that there are variations...will try out and let you know all how it goes :)

Answer (score 2):

Actually, the best way to check for whether a value exists or not in `Cache` is by doing:

```
//string is used as an example; you should put the type you expect
string variable = Cache["KEY"] as string;

if(variable!=null)
{
  // do something
}
```

The reason why doing `if(Cache["KEY"]!=null) myVariable=Cache["Key"];` is unsafe, is because the object stored in `Cache["Key"]` may be removed from `Cache` before you get a chance to assign it to `myVariable` and you end up thinking that myVariable holds a non-null value.

Answer (score 1):

You obviously only setting one of the cache entries at a time. So unless you run the "setter" code 3 times with only 1 variable set to true, then you always going to have nulls returned. 
`null` does not cast into `bool` because its a value type. Try using `bool?`

Answer (score 0):

Since Cache[] returns an object, which is null if not set, then you're getting an exception trying to cast null into a bool.

You'd have to check if that key exists first, or you'd have to set each key to "false" as a default.